# Handling logic in dumb component

Tags: reactjs

Is the following the right way to handle some logic in dumb components in React?

```
const MyDumbContainer = ({myObject}) => {

   const myRenderFunction = () {

      if(myObject === null) return null;

      return(
         <div>
            {myObject.someData}
         </div>
      );
   }

   return(
      <div>{myRenderFunction()}</div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Move the `myRenderFunction` out and pass `myObject` as an argument.

Comment: Do you mean move the logic out of the dumb component and do not even call it?

Comment: No, I mean you're redefining the same function every call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More elegantly:

```
const MyDumbContainer = ({ myObject }) => (myObject !== null)
    ? <div>{myObject.someData}</div>
    : null
}
```

Comment: It produces the different result though

Comment: you mean the missing additional wrapping `<div>`? I think it is unnecessary.

Comment: Yep, with that you would have duplicated logic (or it would be hardly readable)